# Как отсортировать массив без участия логического оператора?Cи

Tags: c, массивы, for

Условие задачи - использовать одномерный массив целых чисел, который заполнить произвольными целыми числами. Вывести на экран значения элементов с парными индексами (2, 4, 6, …) не используя оператор проверки условия. Вычислить сумму этих частей.Я просто не понимаю,каким образом это можно сделать без **IF/ELSE**?.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double mass[7] = {1,2,5,6,8,11,15};
    for (int i = 0;i < 7;i++){
          mass[i] /= 2;
    }
    for (int i = 0;i < 7;i++){
        printf("%f\n",mass[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (unsigned q=0; q<n; q+=2)
```